# Accessibility missing from the Privacy tab

Tags: macos, accessibility

While installing drivers for my drawing tablet on my macbook. I went to go look for the accessibility option in the privacy tab. In the image shown below, the accessibility option is just not there, and have not been able to find a solution to fix it.

I am the only user of the laptop, and I have admin privileges. I run macOS  / OS X 10.8.5

[image]

Am I missing something here, or is there something wrong with the laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of macOS predates this setting. You don’t have any restrictions to grant as they are not in place.

Can you validate your macOS version (or perhaps it’s still called OS X) from About this Mac and also cross reference the driver software version and requirement?

If in the end it’s not working, we might need a follow on question documenting the versions for someone to help. Since there are dozens of macos versions and many dozens of accessories that have tablet form, it’s not likely there’s a single solution for all cases you report of the hardware not working.

Nothing is likely wrong other than perhaps the wrong version of OS or wrong instructions being followed for the install.

Comment: My OS version is 10.8.5.

Comment: I just checked the manufacturer's website, that they only support 10.10 and above. thanks!